# Unable to find expand option in virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a ubuntu installed in my virtual box which is running out of space

I am following [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/124622/how-to-enlarge-a-virtual-machines-disk-in-virtualbox-or-vmware/) to solve my problem,the command given below worked fine

```
VBoxManage.exe modifyhd “C:\Users\ABC\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu.vdi” –resize 20480
```

In the next step they instructed to go on virtual machine settings->hard disk->utilities->expand

But i cant find the expand option in my virtual machine->settings->storage.

It shows me a virtual memory 20 GB and actual size of 7.98 GB

**How can i expand thr actual size to 20 GB**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand the instructions that you linked to. The "virtual machine settings->hard disk->utilities->expand" section is for VMWare users. You're not using VMWare, you're using Virtualbox. You have already enlarged the virtual hard drive using the Virtualbox utility. The hard disk file isn't 20GB in size because nothing has been written to the additional space yet.

Your actual next step is to go into the guest and get the guest to use the additional space. You could try following the instructions in your article in the section "Enlarge the Virtual Machine’s Partition". Here are some other pages that also describe the process:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/ResizingPartition
- http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-resize-partitions-with-the-ubuntu-or-gparted-live-cd